# Ejabberd - Error while processing SQL Query

Tags: sql, erlang, ejabberd

I'm writing a module in ejabberd using hooks. In it, I fire a SQL query as follow:-

```
?INFO_MSG("Packet Type:- `~p` ~n ~n ~n", [sql_queries:get_privacy_list_names_t("praful")]);
```

`sql_queries` is another module in ejabberd and `get_privacy_list_names_t` is the function in it.

```
get_privacy_list_names_t(LUser) ->
    ejabberd_sql:sql_query_t(
      ?SQL("select @(name)s from privacy_list"
           " where username=%(LUser)s")).
```

It returns an error saying:-

```
11:50:34.790 [error] Internal error while processing SQL query: {error,{badrecord,state},[{ejabberd_sql,sql_query_internal,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sql.erl"},{line,526}]},{ejabberd_sql,sql_query_t,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sql.erl"},{line,180}]},{mod_sunshine,user_receive_packet,1,[{file,"src/mod_sunshine.erl"},{line,27}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,380}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,364}]},{ejabberd_c2s,process_info,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,231}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,380}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,364}]}]}
```

What exactly is the error?

It says, `badrecord`. What is this? I couldnt find such exception in erlang !!

Comment: On line 526 of `ejabberd_sql.erl`, the code tries to access a record field in a variable, but that variable doesn't actually contain a `state` record. (The error message doesn't say what it actually contained.)

Comment: Sorry, didnt get you. Is this what you are referring? https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_sql.erl#L526

Comment: Doesn't look like the exact same version, so the line numbers are off. I guess the error happens on a line like `case State#state.db_type of` - it tries to access the `db_type` field in the `state` record contained in the variable `State`, but if `State` doesn't actually contain a `state` record, you'll get a `badrecord` error. (As for _why_ `State` has the wrong value, I have no idea, I'm afraid.)

Comment: It looks like you should call `sql_queries:get_privacy_list_names` instead of `sql_queries:get_privacy_list_names_t`, as the functions with the `_t` suffix should only be called from within an SQL transaction.

Comment: What do you mean by within a transaction? Didnt get you?

Comment: @legoscia - Can you also provide your valuable advice to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543033/ejabberd-create-a-custom-stanza-get-set-subtags It will be very helpful!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @legoscia, `sql_queries:get_privacy_list_names` instead of `sql_queries:get_privacy_list_names_t`, as the functions with the `_t` suffix should only be called from within an SQL transaction.

```
functionname(LServer, Param) ->
    ejabberd_sql:sql_query(
        LServer,
        ?SQL("select @(column)s from table "
             "where column=%(Param)s")).
```